# How to make Python types.Method work with "go to definition" in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, types

I'm using VS Code to write some Python code. I define some methods using `types.MethodType` but when I try to "go to definition" in VS Code, it complains - "No definition found for foo".

```py
# An example
import types


class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = "a"


def _foo(obj):
    print(obj.a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    a.foo = types.MethodType(_foo, a)

    a.foo()
```

Is there a way to make this work in VS Code?

I want to be able to ctrl+click on `a.foo()` and be taken to `def _foo(obj)`.

Comment: I'm not sure, I doubt it, VSCode probably relies on static analysis that can't handle this approach

Comment: If you want to dynamically add methods to a class, assign the function itself to the *class*; don't add bound methods to the instance. `A.foo = _foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not surprised that VS Code doesn't provide you with "Go to Definition" here. While it's not impossible in the specific scenario you've shown for static analysis to be able to follow what's going on, what you're doing with dynamically (at runtime) adding a method to an object is not something that generalizes well for static analysis (Ex. imagine if `_foo` was an element of an array of functions, and was picked out of that array at runtime by choosing a random number, or reading a number from a file at runtime. Static analysis would be unable to do what you are asking for).

You *could* [write a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new) to the maintainers of the Python extension, but I'm personally doubtful that they'll budge to support this, since in the big scale of things, I'd imagine that this particular scenario is something rather niche (not something that the average person would write).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.